# Assigning javascript variable using php

Tags: php, javascript, session, include

Im trying to load a map using the google map api. I have a script that centers it on a given lcation, specified in: var address = "my address";

The session holds a part of a path to a txt file that has the address in it.

This is a bit messy, but it serves a purpose :-)

Here is the javascript with php:

```
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                <?php
                    $center_path = "images\blog\\".$_SESSION['trip']."\\Center.txt";
                    echo "var address = \"";
                    include($center_path);
                    echo "\";";
                ?>

                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    } 
                });
```

This outputs

var address = "my address";

in the html wich would mean it should work, only it doesn't.

Does anybody know why the variable address isn't being passed along properly?

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". What *does* it do?

Comment: have you tried with firebug to see if the address variable exists ? have a look to the generated source if the content of the string for address is on the same line, maybe it outputs on many lines and javascript can't parse it. Firebug reports any javascript errors?

Comment: Have you checked the session to see if 'trip' exists? Also, echo out that path to see what it looks like...

Answer (score 0):

You are using a relative path to the file.  Make sure that the file is based off the root.  To debug this use echo $center_path and make sure that the path echoed out is pointing to the file.  If all else fails specify an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using include to get the file, try using file_get_contents. From there, you should properly sanitize the file, and run trim on it. While testing this I noticed that even a single line file held an end of line character, which could cause funny things to happen in the javascript.

As others have said, you should do some due dilligance for yourself, and echo out all the variables, and make sure that they are containing the information that you intended for them.

One thing is, sessions are fickle creatures. You should make sure that your session variable is used exactly as it should, that the $center_path variable is properly cased, and everything is in line as it should be.

Other then that, I'm not sure what else we could do there.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using `file_get_contents` to load a file into a variable instead of `include`, which is used to execute code in the context in which it is called.